# Is it bad practice to include two types of views in the same class?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app, I use a widget with a loading spinner to signify that a network request is waiting.

On failure, there will be another view which contains a failure message and a "Reload" button.

My question is, since both of these views/widgets will ALWAYS be used together (either one or the other will be shown - or neither), should I merge them into a single widget? Would that be bad or good practice? That way I wouldn't have to prepare them both whenever I want to use one of them.

The main disadvantage I see is that modularity would be destroyed.

Comment: Oh, I don't know that modularity would be totally destroyed, especially if you know that it's not going to matter anyway.  If you're worried about it, couldn't you create a composite widget that incorporates the two original ones, but leave the original ones intact so that you could use them separately from the composite widget?

Comment: Good idea. Make it an answer.

Comment: I wouldn't know the first thing about how to do it in Objective C.  It's simple OO composition, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise this has been asked a while ago now but I thought I'd throw in my two cents.

I'm actually working on a project that is doing something like this at the minute. My opinion would be to not do this, unless all of your use cases can follow the same logic.

I've had an issue where there was a component that handles errors and displays messages to the user. It has inbuilt responses e.g.

- Sorry couldn't connect to servers, please try again
- We seem to be facing technical difficulties, please try again later
- You don't seem to have a data connection

etc.

The main issue with this is that the error messages are being taken out of context. Receiving generic error A on the first screen might throw up "Sorry we couldn't connect", however I don't want to show that on the screen where you put through an order, I want to say, for example "Your order couldn't be processed at this time".

What you could very easily do is create a super class for error handlers, then you could create different subclasses and pass one of those into your "Single widget" as an init parameter, that would keep your modularity intact.

However the big issue I see with this is the overhead associated in doing this, given that customers always want little changes here and there. When this happens its a lot of reworking / creating another widget, just to get a piece of text to show up on the screen.

My opinion is that error situations are best off being handled by passing in a failure block of some kind. The logic to display a custom alert view can be abstracted away, but it can be common for different situations to necessitate different messages for the same error.

As I said earlier if you are in a situation where nothing will ever change (do you ever really know though?), then go for it, less duplicate code is always a plus.

Comment: That is actually a good idea, a delegate may be a decent way to do it as well.

Comment: @elimirks yep, delegates will work great too. I feel blocks get over used, had an issue where I had 6 blocks inside each other due to components, code was just unreadable. However, I will say that having a block as a parameter in an init is much clearer to another user using the component than having to figure out to use the delegate. That is probably why they are used so much, but I would be more up for separating the code as much as possible, to which delegates work better